# Рассудите, пожалуйста, кто прав

Tags: пунктуация

В общем, предложение такое:

*1, 2, 5 (у всей фирмы выходной), 14, 15, 22, 23, 31.*

Вопрос такой. В предложении смысл в том, что у всей фирмы выходной 1, 2, 5? Или смысл в том,что у всей фирмы выходной 5? И дальше перечисление других чисел.

Как влияет пунктуация на смысл предложения? Моё мнение, что 1, 2, 5 - это перечисление выходных фирмы, указанных в скобках. Мнение оппонента, что содержимое скобок касается только пятого числа - последнего перед скобками.

Заранее прошу прощения, я, увы, не спец в пунктуации, но очень уж хочется разобраться.

Comment: Вы не могли бы привести контекст, в текущем виде предложение не имеет смысла и представляет собой просто перечисление цифр.

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном Вами предложении чего-то недостаёт. Существенного причём.

Ведь если убрать скобки (со словами внутри), то у нас останется что-то вроде натурального ряда чисел с некоторыми пустотами, - о какой пунктуации тут можно говорить?

А пунктуация, если б было к чему её применить, могла бы выглядеть так (и влиять на смысл):

*1, 2, 5 (у всей фирмы выходной), 14, 15, 22, 23, 31 (по графику рабочего дня).*

И всё равно предложение странноватое, понятнее было бы, например так:

*Режим работы предприятия в июле 2017 г.: 1, 2, 5 (у всей фирмы выходной), 14, 15, 22, 23, 31 (по графику рабочего дня).*

(Подразумевая, что пропущенные числа месяца падают на официальные выходные - субботы и воскресенья или перечислены приёмные дни - *пон, ср, пят.* К примеру.)

Тогда прав тот из спорящих, кто пояснение в скобках относит к группе чисел, упомянутых до скобок, вместо которых - по-хорошему - должно стоять тире:

***Режим работы предприятия в июле 2017 г.: 1, 2, 5 - у всей фирмы выходной; 14, 15, 22, 23, 31 - по графику рабочего дня.***

Если же попытаться прочесть, как Вы предлагаете, что пояснение в скобках относится к последнему числу, пятому, требуется пояснить значение прочих чисел,

у нас  получилось "предложение":

*1, 2, 14, 15, 22, 23, 31.*

А пятого - у всей фирмы выходной.

---

Нужно разъяснить етую сову! )))

Answer (score 1):

1, 2 и 5-го — у всей фирмы выходной.

(а) Наращение для порядковых числительных необходимы, а в случае перечисления в начале фразы — особенно. (b) Скобки имеют обыкновение включать пояснения и уточнения только для предыдущего слова, и их применение здесь не приводит к необходимой информационной чёткости.